# Child route does not trigger

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am building this route system

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider
    .when('/admin', '/admin/dashboard')
    .when('/user', '/user/dashboard')
    .otherwise('/admin/dashboard');

  $stateProvider
    .state('admin', {
      url: '/admin/dashboard',
      resolve: {
        test: function() {
          console.log('called admin');
          return;
        }
      },      
      views: {
        'navigation': {
          template: '<div>admin navigation. Go <a ui-sref="admin.link1">link1</a></div>'
        },
        'content': {
          template: '<div>admin dashboard</div>'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('admin.link1', { //for some reason admin.link1 does not work but just link1 is OK
      url: '/admin/link1',
      resolve: {
        test: function() {
          console.log('admin.link1 called resolve');
          return;
        }
      },
      views: {
        'navigation': {
          template: '<div>admin navigation</div>'
        },
        'content': {
          template: '<div>admin link1</div>'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('user', {
      url: '/user/dashboard',
      views: {
        'navigation': {
          template: '<div>user navigation</div>'
        },
        'content': {
          template: '<div>user dashboard</div>'
        }
      }
    });
});
```

The HTML will have `navigation` and `content` `ui-view` in it

```
  <body ng-app="plunker">
    <div>
      <a ui-sref="admin">Admin</a>
      <a ui-sref="user">User</a>
    </div>
    <div ui-view="navigation"></div>
    <div ui-view="content"></div>  
  </body>
```

I want to click on `link1` and go to `admin.link1` state but somehow that is not working.

But if I remove the `admin` parent and use `link1` only, it works fine.

Code: http://plnkr.co/edit/F7lw58esXz7rWzeo3ER6?p=preview

Preview: http://embed.plnkr.co/F7lw58esXz7rWzeo3ER6/preview

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there, the updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qOLugNWhwfPSDf3sfuzN?p=preview). There is only one change the nested views do have appended sign **'@'**:

```
.state('admin.link1', {
  url: '/admin/link1',
  resolve: {
    test: function() {
      console.log('admin.link1 called resolve');
      return;
    }
  },
  views: {
    // instead of this
    // 'navigation': {
    // we have to use absolute name with the @ at the end
    'navigation@': {
      template: '<div>admin navigation</div>'
    },
    // this is searched in parent view
    // 'content': {
    // this is targting the root
    'content@': {
      template: '<div>admin link1</div>'
    }
  }
})
```

The point is hidden in the [absolut view naming](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names), an extract:

> Behind the scenes, every view gets assigned an absolute name that follows a scheme of **`viewname@statename`**, where viewname is the name used in the view directive and state name is the state's absolute name, e.g. contact.item. You can also choose to write your view names in the absolute syntax.

The working example(s) [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qOLugNWhwfPSDf3sfuzN?p=preview) or other [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0QgMkFXEFna5mT0HIv2S?p=preview)

*Please, try to read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24749774/1679310), where I tried deeply describe what is the view naming about.(search for a last section: EXTEND: to give THE answer to a comment)*