# Make child route as default

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I asked a similar case here but then I found out it was not exactly what I wanted to do:

[Child route does not trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24813109/child-route-does-not-trigger)

Here is a new version:

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-app="plunker">
    <div>
      <a ui-sref="admin">Admin</a>
      <a ui-sref="user">User</a>
    </div>
    <div ui-view></div>  
  </body>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider
    .when('/', '/admin/dashboard')
    .when('/admin', '/admin/dashboard')
    .when('/user', '/user/dashboard')
    .otherwise('/admin/dashboard');

  $stateProvider
    .state('admin.dashboard', {
      url: '/admin/dashboard',
      resolve: {
        test: function() {
          console.log('called admin');
          return;
        }
      },
      template: '<div>admin navigation. Go <a ui-sref="admin.link1">link1</a></div>'
    })
    .state('admin.link1', { //for some reason admin.link1 does not work but just link1 is OK
      url: '/admin/link1',
      resolve: {
        test: function() {
          console.log('admin.link1 called resolve');
          return;
        }
      },
      template: '<div>admin link1</div>'
    })
    .state('user', {
      url: '/user/dashboard',
      template: '<div>user dashboard</div>'
    });
});
```

CODE: http://plnkr.co/edit/NYdWC1j9xskQnY8LjJkZ?p=preview

**Requirements**

1. I don't need to render anything for parent routes (`admin`)
2. The default redirect will be `/admin/dashboard`
3. I need the url to be properly structure as child of `/admin` because previous question, it ended up to be `/admin/dashboard/admin/link1`
4. I do need `admin` and `user` parents. There is a need for children relationship. This will be used later.

**Problems**

1. Right now I cannot show child routes like `admin.dashboard`. It's just blank. How to show `dashboard` by default?
2. If I added the lines below to show the `admin` template, even this `ui-sref="admin.dashboard"` won't take me to the correct `dashboard` child route

`javascript
    .state('admin', {
      url: '/admin',
      template: '<div>admin. Go <a ui-sref="admin.dashboard">dashboard</a></div>'
    })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CrRoWDUcnMiyDrErPSyo?p=preview). To make things simple, I firstly changed the name of the state `'admin.dashboard'` into:

```
.state('admin_dashboard', {
  url: '/admin/dashboard',
  ...
```

the reason is, that any **dot** is here treated as a sub-state. And we can *(but do not have to)* introduce substate of *admin* now, to explain how to call that `state` properly...

And these are the essential changes in the **call** inside of the `<a>`

**not** working ui-sref (original)

```
<div>
  <a ui-sref="admin">Admin</a>
  <a ui-sref="user">User</a>
</div>
```

**working** ui-sref

```
<div>
  <a ui-sref="admin_dashboard">Admin</a>
  <a ui-sref="user">User</a>
</div>
```

**working** href

```
<div>
  <a href="#/">Admin as <samp>'/'</samp></a>
  <a href="#/admin">Admin as <samp>'/Admin'</samp></a>
  <a href="#/user">User</a>
</div>
```

as we can see, the `ui-sref` must contain the **state name**, while the `href` can (must) contain the url, even the one defined inside of the  `when()`

Check the updated [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/CrRoWDUcnMiyDrErPSyo?p=preview)...

UPDATE:

In case that we would like to go with the parent child, we can have the setting like this

```
$stateProvider
     .state('admin', {
       url: '/admin',
       template: '<div>admin. Go <a ui-sref="admin.dashboard">dashboard</a>' + 
       '<div ui-view=""></div>' +
       '</div>'
     })
    .state('admin.dashboard', {
      url: '/dashboard',
      resolve: {
        test: function() {
          console.log('called admin');
          return;
        }
      },
      template: '<div>admin navigation. Go <a ui-sref="admin.link1">link1</a></div>'
    })
    .state('admin.link1', { 
      url: '/link1',
      resolve: {
        test: function() {
          console.log('admin.link1 called resolve');
          return;
        }
      },
      template: '<div>admin link1</div>'
    })
    .state('user', {
      url: '/user/dashboard',
      template: '<div>user dashboard</div>'
    });
```

and these would be the anchors

**not** working ui-sref (original)

```
<div>
  <a ui-sref="admin">Admin</a>
  <a ui-sref="user">User</a>
</div>
```

**working** ui-sref

```
<div>
  <a ui-sref="admin.dashboard">Admin</a>
  <a ui-sref="user">User</a>
</div>
```

**working** href

```
<div>
  <a href="#/">Admin as <samp>'/'</samp></a>
  <a href="#/admin">Admin as <samp>'/Admin'</samp></a>
  <a href="#/user">User</a>
</div>
```

And the updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CrRoWDUcnMiyDrErPSyo?p=preview)

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear. I thought of doing flat and no parent/children before but I think I do need the parent state.

Comment: Not an issue ;) I just updted the plunker, to show you how easy is to introduce the parent child... you have to love `ui-router` ... it is a really **aaawesome** tool ;)

Comment: I love `angular-ui-router` !!

Answer (score 1):

When nesting routes you need to have a parent route. In this case you are missing an 'admin' route.

```
.state('admin', {
    url: '/admin',
    abstract: true,
    template: '<div ui-view></div>'
})
.state('admin.dashboard', {
    url: '/dashboard',
    templateUrl: '/views/admin.dashboard.html'
})
.state('admin.profile', {
    url: '/profile',
    templateUrl: '/views/profile.html'
})
```

1. the `abstract: true` attribute tells ui-router that this isn't actually a route you can navigate to
2. the nesting of routes is implied by the `.` in the name
3. routes are then `/admin/dashboard` and `/admin/profile`

see: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#issue-my-templates-are-not-appearing--loading—showing (re: missing `ui-view`/blank view problem)

Comment: Yes this is almost what I needed: http://plnkr.co/edit/aCQ3SV5uAimuU0F3ITSr?p=preview. But how to make `admin` to redirect to `admin.dashboard` though? Basically parent to a child of it. Right now I had to modify the `<a ui-sref="admin.dashboard">Admin</a>`

Comment: I found out `abstract: true` disabled redirect. Strange. This works now: http://plnkr.co/edit/aCQ3SV5uAimuU0F3ITSr?p=preview