# In AngularJS, loaded content by ui-view cannot read javascript file in parent content

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, uiview, angular-ui-router

I want to insert header and nav bar into index.html

When header and nav bar are in index.html, My app works well.

but seperate these files to html and try to load, ui-view do not load script files.

So logout function does not work when ui-view loaed header.html

On the other hand, css works well.

I tried to follow answers like

[Angularjs does not load scripts within ng-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220197/angularjs-does-not-load-scripts-within-ng-view)

or

[html partial is not loaded into ui-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25068648/html-partial-is-not-loaded-into-ui-view)

but it did not help to fix my problem..

Why this situation occurred?

Please any handsome or pretty developer help me..

These are my code.

## app.js

```
'use strict';

var mainApp = angular
.module('adminApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ui.router'
]);

mainApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/admin/login');
    $stateProvider
    .state('root',{
        url: '',
        abstract: true,
        views: {
            'headerContainer': {
                templateUrl: 'views/header.html',
                controller: 'HeaderCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'header'
            },
            'navContainer':{
                templateUrl: 'views/nav.html',
                controller: 'NavCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'nav'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('root.login', {
        ...
    })
});
```

## index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="adminApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Admin</title>

    <base href="/">

    <!-- CSS-->
    <link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Font-icon css-->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- start: Favicon -->
    <link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
    <!-- end: Favicon -->

</head>
<body class="sidebar-mini fixed" ng-controller="AppCtrl">

<div class="wrapper">

    <div ui-view="headerContainer"></div>
    <div ui-view="navContainer"></div>

    <div ui-view="appContainer"></div>

</div>

<!-- Javascripts-->
<script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/main.js" ></script>
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/headerCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/navCtrl.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

## header.html

```
<header class="main-header hidden-print">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top">
        <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
            <ul class="top-nav">
                <li>
                    <a ng-click="logout();">Logout</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

## headerCtrl.js

```
mainApp.controller('HeaderCtrl', function ($scope, $cookieStore) {

    $scope.logout = function () {
        angular.forEach($cookies.getAll(), function (v, k) {
            $cookies.remove(k);
        });     //  This is for remove all cookies
    };
});
```

## main.js

```
$('.top-nav li a').on('click', function (e) {
    console.log('Clicked header li');
});
```

Comment: Try using relative path like templateUrl: '/views/header.html',

Comment: @Vivz I tried that just now, but still not working.. thanks to your comment.

Comment: Can you show your headerCtrl.js and what is present inside main.js?

Comment: @Vivz I just added else code.

Comment: Check the below answer and see if it is working or not?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you haven't used controller alias while calling `logout` method

```
ng-click="header.logout();"
```

Comment: this didn't work for me. Actually, I write the code in main.js to see console logs when I click that, but any logs was not appeared.

Comment: @CanetRobern Can you please provide a plunker?

Comment: I am really sorry but, I just started learn developing.. so I don't know how to use plunker..

Answer (score 1):

As @pankaj said you need to declare the logout method on your controller alias

```
ng-click="header.logout();"
```

And the same applies for your js. You have to reference logout with **this** keyword since you are using controller as syntax

```
mainApp.controller('HeaderCtrl', function ($scope, $cookieStore) {
    var vm =this;
    vm.logout = function () {
        angular.forEach($cookies.getAll(), function (v, k) {
            $cookies.remove(k);
        });     //  This is for remove all cookies
    };
});
```

**For more Info**: [AngularJs "controller as" syntax - clarification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287794/angularjs-controller-as-syntax-clarification)

Comment: I don't think this code working because, even function to see log in main.js did not work.

Comment: Try to put a debugger inside logout and see if the function is getting called

Comment: well, I did what you said but I've got nothing.

Comment: Nothings in console.