# Angular doesn't load state if I use abstract parent state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

There is the following code:

```
angular.module('app', ['app.animators', 'app.events', 'app.hotel', 'app.controllers', 'app.services', 'ui.router', 'templates', 'ngResource', 'ngCookies', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngImgCrop', 'angularjs-dropdown-multiselect']).config(['$httpProvider', '$locationProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', ($httpProvider, $locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) ->
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/404")

  $stateProvider.state('signIn'
    url: '/admin/signin'
    controller: 'SignInController'
    templateUrl: 'signin.html'
  )

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
])
```

It works good, but I change it to the following code:

```
angular.module('app', ['app.animators', 'app.events', 'app.hotel', 'app.controllers', 'app.services', 'ui.router', 'templates', 'ngResource', 'ngCookies', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngImgCrop', 'angularjs-dropdown-multiselect']).config(['$httpProvider', '$locationProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', ($httpProvider, $locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) ->
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/404")

  $stateProvider.state('admin.signIn'
    url: '/admin/signin'
    controller: 'SignInController'
    templateUrl: 'signin.html'
  ).state('admin'
    abstract: true
  )

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
])
```

It doesn't work, i.e. I enter the address `'http://localhost/admin/signin'`, browser is loading, but I don't get 'signin.html' template. I need to use 'admin' state in order to use a 'resolve' function for all child states (my example is not complete). What's the trouble ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost **each parent** should have a **template** - the one which will be a **target for its child**. There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Nw90tUULbWAckbSJBrgj?p=preview).

So just adding this line to the parent definition: **`template: "<div ui-view></div>"`** - will make that code working:

```
.state('admin', {
  abstract: true,
  template: "<div ui-view></div>"
})
```

What happened is - child does have its target, the anchor where it could be injected.

*There could be other solution, e.g. child is targeting the root `ui-view=""` ... but above solution is appropriate... See [View Names - Relative vs. Absolute Names](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names), check this answer and its plunker with more examples of [absolute name targeting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25678843/1679310)*

Check it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Nw90tUULbWAckbSJBrgj?p=preview)