# Render different layouts via ng-route or angular-ui-router | Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-route

I need to segment backend to dashboard layout and login layout. It must be two different layouts.

How I can implement this using angular-ui-router?

**index.html**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    ...
    <div id="page-wrapper" ui-view>
    ...
```

**JS**

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider.
        state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'assets/templates/login.html',
            controller: 'AuthCtrl'
        }).
        state('/products', {
            url: '/products',
            templateUrl: 'assets/templates/product-list.html',
            controller: 'ProductListCtrl'
        }).
        state('/categories', {
            url: '/categories',
            templateUrl: 'assets/templates/category-list.html',
            controller: 'CategoryListCtrl'
        }).
        state('/product/add', {
            url: '/product/add',
            templateUrl: 'assets/templates/add-product.html',
            controller: 'AddProductCtrl'
        }).
        ...
}]);
```

Comment: *What is the best way* is not kind of question to be solved here, I'd say. Is something not working? *(BEST is surprisingly "answerer" dependent...)*

Comment: Yes) I can't figure out how exactly is segmenting to different layouts working if both layout will be in the same root index file..)

Comment: *I can give you some hints like this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25667660/1679310 (which I guess is really close to your scenario)  or that  http://stackoverflow.com/q/28800644/1679310 but.. it depends on app real needs. I could tell you how many time I had to change what I thought is the best*

Comment: That helped? great ;) Enjoy mighty UI-Router ;)

Comment: @RadimKöhler, not exactly) I've found some solution that I like a little bit more :) Take a look, maybe you'll find it useful. Thanks once more for your time ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found pretty much good solution for multiple layots routing in Angular [here](http://angular-route-segment.com/).

It is based on built-in Angular's $route engine, which extends it for advanced routing in Angularjs.

Also want to add that it is very simple to use and read, very intuitive.

For better understanding below is example of solving my particular issue. Everything works well.

```
app.config(['$routeSegmentProvider', function($routeSegmentProvider){
    $routeSegmentProvider.

        when('/',             'main').
        when('/products',     'main.products').
        when('/product/add',  'main.productAdd').
        when('/categories',   'main.categories').
        when('/category/add', 'main.categoryAdd').
        when('/login',        'login').

        ...

        segment('main', {
            templateUrl: 'assets/templates/home.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'}).

        within().
            segment('products', {
                default: true,
                templateUrl: 'assets/templates/product-list.html',
                controller: 'ProductListCtrl'}).
            segment('productAdd', {
                templateUrl: 'assets/templates/add-product.html',
                controller: 'AddProductCtrl'}).
            segment('categories', {
                templateUrl: 'assets/templates/category-list.html',
                controller: 'CategoryListCtrl'}).
            segment('categoryAdd', {
                templateUrl: 'assets/templates/add-category.html',
                controller: 'AddCategoryCtrl'}).
            up().

        segment('login', {
            templateUrl: 'assets/templates/login.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'});
        ...
}]);
```

Comment: This sounds to me like a really god solution! great job

Comment: @RadimKöhler heh) I'd better say thanks to the author of this extension)