# Creating layouts with multiple nested views using angular-ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I have tried several examples on using the ui-router and the state manager. My nested views and routes are not working as I hoped. Here is an example of how I am configuring the states:

```
          $stateProvider                
            .state("main", {
                abstract: true,
                url: "/main",
                views: {
                    "layout": {
                        templateUrl: "main.index.html"
                    },
                    "mainNavigation@main": {
                        templateUrl: "main-navigation-partial.html"
                    }
                },
                onEnter: function() {
                    console.log("enter main");
                }
            })
            .state("main.dashboard", {
                url: "/dashboard",

                views: {
                    "container@main": {
                        templateUrl:"main-dashboard.html"
                    }
                }
            });
```

As you can see, I have an abstract state named `main`. All main views will use the `mainNavigation` view. There is also a container view area where the content for each section will reside. There is an `index.html` that will be used by all states. So, I may, down the road have an abstract state name `client` with accompanying states and views.

I can see the individual html files being loaded, but the views are not being populated in the correct named view areas. I have [created a plunk](http://plnkr.co/qsXK488D6S1XS25dSQI0) that demonstrates how I want to manage my templates and views.

Comment: Also check these http://stackoverflow.com/q/25667660/1679310 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/28800644/1679310

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main state is loading main.index.html into a ui-view named `layout`. In your plunker, your root ui-view is unnamed. So to fix this, add a name to that ui-view.

http://plnkr.co/edit/xKDcuk99OACQR73LR0hf?p=preview

```
<div ui-view='layout'>
```

Or, you could leave the ui-view unnamed and change the view to reflect that.

```
"": {
  templateUrl: "main.index.html"
}
```

For more on view naming, see the [ui-router wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names).

Comment: I assumed I could leave the index.html ui-view blank and everything would just load in there. Apparently not. I took your advice and left the view name blank and it works well. Thanks!