# Angular ui-router : Container view and Default view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, state, angular-ui-router

I am struggling to create a container for next states, defined the states as views, divided into header, CONTAINER, footer.

The next state as an example would be the blogs, but I do not see a way of getting it into the view.

One idea was to start the HOME view as standard, but also failed.

view:

```
<main>

    <header ui-view="header"></header>
    <content ui-view="home"></content>
    <footer ui-view="footer"></footer>

</main>
```

states:

```
.state('home',{
        url:'/',
        data: {
            pageTitle: 'Home'
        },
        views: {
            '': {
                templateUrl: 'content/index.html',
            },
            'header@home': {
                templateUrl: 'content/templates/header.html',
                controller: 'HeaderController',
                cache: false
            },
            'home@home': {
                templateUrl: 'content/templates/home.html',
                controller: 'IndexController',
                cache: false
            },
            'footer@home': {
                templateUrl: 'content/templates/footer.html',
                //controller: 'FooterController',
                cache: false
            }
        }
    })

.state('home.blog',{
        url         : '/blog',
        templateUrl : 'content/templates/blog.html',
        controller  : 'BlogController',
        data: { pageTitle: 'Blog' },
        access: {requiredLogin: false}
    })
```

SUCCESS! :)

Plunker Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/yRgqiAeEVQl2WVajGgG0?p=preview

Comment: are header and footer global? If so can make home a parent state and only change the content view in child states

Comment: Yes, its global. I tried to follow his tip, but am still unable to transition between views. I will create a Plunker

Comment: Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/yRgqiAeEVQl2WVajGgG0?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the updated question above, you've used [this plunker to show](http://plnkr.co/edit/yRgqiAeEVQl2WVajGgG0?p=preview) how you made it working:

```
.state('home',{
    url:'',
    abstract: true,
    views: {
        '': {
            templateUrl: 'index.html'    // this
        },
        'header@home': {
            templateUrl: 'header.html'

        },
        'footer@home': {
            templateUrl: 'footer.html'
        }
    }
})
.state('home.index',{
    url         : '/',
    templateUrl : 'home.html'
})
.state('home.blog',{
    url         : '/blog',
    templateUrl : 'blog.html',
});
```

While that solution is working, it is in fact **not** a way you/we should go. Because the parent state 'home', injects into unnamed view **`itslef`** - `templateUrl: 'index.html'`

So, now there are again views **header** and **footer**, but they do differ from the root *(original `index.htm`)*. Their absolute name would be 'header@home' and 'footer@home' *(as used int the code snippet)* - and all seems to be working.

But that is redundant. Unless we will move the layout into some 'layout' state and 'layout.html'

- [Angular UI Router - Nested States with multiple layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25667660/1679310)
- [Nested states or views for layout with leftbar in ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28800644/1679310)

Why redundant? Because `index.html` already is in play *(as a **`root`**)* and it contains these targets. their absolute name is 'header@' and 'footer@'. And that should be the way to go.

To make it clear, there is [an updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yp8KuHRHJXGVP6UpmXsJ?p=preview) and its snippets:

```
.state('home',{
    url:'',
    abstract: true,
    views: { 
        '': {
            template: '<div ui-view=""></div>'
        },
        'header': {
            templateUrl: 'header.html'

        },
        'footer': {
            templateUrl: 'footer.html'
        }
    }
})
.state('home.index',{
    url         : '/',
    templateUrl : 'home.html'
})
.state('home.blog',{
    url         : '/blog',
    templateUrl : 'blog.html',
});
```

Check the update [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/yp8KuHRHJXGVP6UpmXsJ?p=preview)