# Angular nested router-ui

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

In angular how can I create a route for nested view as follow:

```
/#/app/dashboard
/#/app/product/
/#/app/product/new
```

my current route is:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('app',{
        url: '/app',
        templateUrl: 'views/app.html',
        resolve: loadSequence('modernizr','moment'),
        abstract: true
    })
    .state('app.dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html',
        title: 'Dashboard',
        ncyBreadcrumb: {
            label: 'Dashboard'
    }
    }).state('app.product', {
        url: '/product',
        templateUrl: "views/product.html",
        title: 'Buttons',
        resolve: loadSequence('ngTable', 'ngTableCtrl')

    }).state('app.product.new', {
        parent: 'app.product',
        url: '/new',
        templateUrl: "views/add_product.html",
        title: 'Buttons',
        resolve: loadSequence('ngTable', 'ngTableCtrl')
    })
```

This issues is, viewing `/#/app/product/new` render back the `/#/app/product`. Where the problem is? How does nested view works for angular?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept as you presented that above, is working. I created [sample working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uoybLOK2d0Vek7ngm1zF?p=preview) to show that this kind of state flow is working:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('app',{
        url: '/app', 
        templateUrl: 'views/app.html',
        abstract: true
    })
    .state('app.dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html'
    }).state('app.product', {
        url: '/product',
        templateUrl: "views/product.html",
    }).state('app.product.new', {
        parent: 'app.product',
        url: '/new',
        templateUrl: "views/add_product.html",
    })
```

These links work and do navigate as expected:

```
<a href="#/app/dashboard">
<a href="#/app/product">
<a href="#/app/product/new">
```

The only way, how I made this link

```
<a href="#/app/product/new/">
```

to navigate to its parent *(as stated in the question)*, is by 1) having the default rdirection like this:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/product');
```

And as example above shows - by using wrong link

```
// check the trailing /
<a href="#/app/product/new/">
// this will work
<a href="#/app/product/new">
```

Summary, the concept is ok. There is no built in reason to navigate from `#/app/product/new` to `#/app/product`

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/uoybLOK2d0Vek7ngm1zF?p=preview)

#### EXTEND

As provided - this is [the broken plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dWP5F69i15zThSAQtyP7). Which I fixed [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/FFPQPubRQaN1WFPbuE6d?p=preview)

The first adjustment was the index.html - cleanup

1. remove wrong elements
2. and use NOT MIN angular to see the issue

index.html:

```
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <!--script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.6"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-router@*" src="//rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/0.2.15/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <!--<script>-->
    <script src="app.js"></script> 
  </head>
```

And then, the real issue was wrong reference name 'ui-router' - it should be 'ui.router'

app.js

```
// wrong
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui-router'])
// working
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.router'])
```

*(Based on the comments)* - there is another important featue - target **`<div ui-view>`**. This was added into parent state `'app.product'`.

Reason is - each state (including any child or grand child) must be injected somewhere. And by default it is its parent. So parent `'app.product'` should contain the **`ui-view`** target - for its child `'app.product.new'`.

There are other techniques - called named views and absolute naming which could be in detail observed here:

- [Angular UI Router - Nested States with multiple layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25667660/1679310)
- [Angularjs ui-router not reaching child controller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27457460/1679310)
- [Angular ui-router : Container view and Default view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32771562/1679310)

Working version is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/FFPQPubRQaN1WFPbuE6d?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, but it still rendering app/product page.

Comment: Well, could you tak my plunker, ajdust it to get that issue? If you want, I am ready to assist...

Comment: Hi, the {{$state.current.name}} works correctly, but i had no idea why /product/new displaying /product page. Saw your plunker and I made changes exactly as yours, but the problem still persist

Comment: I took your version, fixed all the issue, extended answer, appended link to working plunker and described some details about that all... hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, looking into it

Comment: Why product has <div ui-view> ? So it means add_product will rendered within this div, am I right?  How if my product page contains an html?

Comment: I again extend my answer to provide more details. Hope that could direct you close to understanding how UI-Router works

Comment: I am really excited to see you've got it! Enjoy mighty UI-Router, sir ;)