# AngularJS ui-router view not showing up?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a very simple appConfig:

```
var home = {
    name: 'home',
    url: '/home/'
};

var homeAccess = {
    name: 'home.access',
    url: 'access',
    views: {
       'home': {
           templateUrl: 'app/access/partials/webapi.html'
       }
    }
};
```

In my index.html I have this code:

```
<div ui-view="home">home view here</div>
```

But when I navigate to the home/access all I see is the words "home view here"

Can anyone see what I might be doing wrong for my access page to not show up.

Comment: Do you have a root ui-view ? Other routes are working ? Any errors on console ? webapi.html is being loaded ?

Comment: These are just a variables, can we assume they are part of a state definition you havn't included in the question?

Comment: @Alon - These have been include in the state definition. Sorry I was just giving a snippet here.

Comment: You have to provide more detail please. The problem can be in any place!

Comment: @JoãoMosmann - no errors and I notice webapi.html was not loaded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root stat *home*, is expecting **unnamed** view target - so index.html should contain it

```
//<div ui-view="home">home view here</div>
<div ui-view="">home view here</div>
```

And the *home* state now should contain target for its child

```
var home = {
    name: 'home',
    url: '/home/',
    template: '<div ui-view="home">home view here</div>'
};
```

Or we can target the root view in our *home.access* state like this '@home':

```
var homeAccess = {
    name: 'home.access',
    url: 'access',
    views: {
       //'home': {
       'home@': {
           templateUrl: 'app/access/partials/webapi.html'
       }
    }
};
```

Check similar here: [Angular UI Router - Nested States with multiple layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25667660/1679310)

Answer (score 4):

As I wrote in the comment, you've only showed us some variables, but you need to change the `views` part:

```
var homeAccess = {
    name: 'home.access',
    url: 'access',
    views: {
       'home@': {
           templateUrl: 'app/access/partials/webapi.html'
       }
    }
};
```