# UI-Router parent view not working in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I'm creating an application and in the dashboard I have the header and the sidebar that will be in every single page of the dashboard, and for that reason I created partial files for them.

**The problem is that if I access `/dashboard/users` I get the same thing that is in the `/dashboard`, I was wondering how to keep the header and sidebar but change the main content to the `/views/dashboard/users.html` file?**

I created the states like this:

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'main'
      })
      .state('dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        views: {
          '': {
            templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html'
          },
          'header@dashboard': {
            templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/partials/header.html'
          },
          'sidebar@dashboard': {
            templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/partials/sidebar.html'
          }
        },
        controller: 'DashboardCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'dashboard'
      })
      .state('dashboard.users', {
        url: '/users',
        views: {
          '': {
            templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/users.html'
          }
        },
        controller: 'DashboardUsersCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'dashboard/users'
      });
});
```

**`/main.html`**

```
<p>main</p>
```

**`/index.html`**

```
<body ng-app="freelancerApp">
    <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

**`/views/dashboard.html`**

```
<div ui-view="header"></div>
<p>dashboard</p>
<div ui-view="sidebar"></div>
```

**`/views/dashboard/users.html`**

```
<div ui-view="header"></div>
<p>users</p>
<div ui-view="sidebar"></div>
```

**`/views/dashboard/partials/header.html`**

```
</p>header</p>
```

**`/views/dashboard/partials/sidebar.html`**

```
<p>sidebar</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say, that your parent template, is just missing place for a child (unnamed view target)

```
//views/dashboard.html
<div ui-view="header"></div>
<p>dashboard</p>
<div ui-view="sidebar"></div>
```

should be

```
//views/dashboard.html
<div ui-view="header"></div>
<div ui-view="">
  // we can keep it or remove the content
  <p>dashboard</p> // just visible in parent
</div>
<div ui-view="sidebar"></div>
```

Now, we have a target `<div ui-view=""></div>` for an unnamed child view, defined as  `views :{ '': {...}}` in a `.state('dashboard.users'...`

Comment: The only problem now is that `<p>dashboard</p>` is still appearing in the `/dashboard` router.

Comment: Check my updated answer. We can have some content inside of unnamed placeholder ui-view... if we want... or it could be left empty... child will anyhow replace the complet `div`

Comment: @molunoluda any progress? I guess now you have it working right? ;)

Comment: Yay, it's working now. I was wondering if my approach is right or I can do that in a different way. I couldn't find any example on the internet that is using the way I'm doing and it made me wonder if I'm doing that right.

Comment: I would say, you are on a good way. really. There are my two favorites http://stackoverflow.com/q/28800644/1679310 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/25667660/1679310. If this answer helped you a bit.. do not forget to accept it ;)

Comment: I would forget, you helped me a lot. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm having a problem... I'm trying to use `ui-sref-active="active"` using this approach in a menu, the thing is that the `/dashboard` keeps activated even if I'm in `/dashboard/users`. How to solve that?

Comment: I would strongly suggest: issue new question. That way you will get larger audience, and for sure you'll get the answer ;) Good luck with UI-Router

Answer (score 0):

Add **abstract:true** in this snippet

```
.state('dashboard', {
    url: '/dashboard',
    abstract: true,
    views: {
      '': {
        templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html'
      },
      'header@dashboard': {
        templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/partials/header.html'
      },
      'sidebar@dashboard': {
        templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/partials/sidebar.html'
      }
    },
    controller: 'DashboardCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'dashboard'
  })
```

Comment: It doesn't work like that, the page still like the `dashboard` and if I keep the `<div ui-view=""></div>` the `<p>dashboard</p>` is still appearing...

Comment: What is the difference using `abstract`? @Radim Köhler