# Multiple named views not showing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, frontend

I'm trying to build from scratch a very simple angular app using ui-router.
Every page will have the same appearance, and will have the following 4 sections (vertically, from top to bottom):

- HEADER (common to all pages)
- HORIZONTAL MENU (common to all pages)
- CONTENT (this is the only content that will change)
- FOOTER (common to all pages)

My `index.html` has `<div ui-view></div>` inside the `<body>` tag.

I also have a simple **html** file (`portal.html`) that contains the structure of every page:

```
<div ui-view="header"></div>
<div ui-view="menu"></div>
<div ui-view="content"></div>
<div ui-view="footer"></div>
```

I've have created a parent state, where I set the common sections to every page:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('portal', {
    url: '/portal',
    templateUrl: 'app/main/portal.html',
    views: {
      header: {
        templateUrl: 'app/main/section/header.html'
      },
      menu: {
        templateUrl: 'app/main/section/menu.html'
      },
      footer: {
        templateUrl: 'app/main/section/footer.html'
      }
    }
  });
```

And some child states (one for each menu option - page), where I set the variable content to every page:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('portal.home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
      'content@portal': {
        controller: 'HomeCtrl as homeVM',
        templateUrl: 'app/portal/home.html'
      }
    },
    resolve: { /* whatever */ }
  })

  // ... and so on ...

  .state('portal.contactUs', {
    url: '/contact-us',
    views: {
      'content@portal': {
        controller: 'ContactUsCtrl as contactUsVM',
        templateUrl: 'app/portal/contactUs.html'
      }
    },
    resolve: { /* whatever */ }
  });
```

But this won't display anything on screen... Am I missing something here?

Comment: I have been researching a little bit, trying different things and lately figured out that what might be causing trouble is the `views` property at the state configuration object passed into `$stateProvider.state()`. 
I wanted it that way to avoid setting those common views `N` times in every child state...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution. What actually helped me was [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25667660/angular-ui-router-nested-states-with-multiple-layouts), that is quite similar to mine, and specially the [plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/I0BJ09BxR7nG9kZDeEIv?p=preview) shown there.

The mistake was in the **state configuration object** passed to the `$stateProvider.state()`. The parent state should be set the following way:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('portal', {
    url: '/portal',
    views: {
      '@': {
        templateUrl: 'app/main/portal.html'
      },
      'header@portal': {
        templateUrl: 'app/main/public/header.html'
      },
      'menu@portal': {
        templateUrl: 'app/main/public/menu.html'
      },
      'footer@portal': {
        templateUrl: 'app/main/public/footer.html'
      }
    }
  });
```