# parent template also displaying on child state. how to get rid off this issue?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using *angular ui router 0.2.15* and there is one page */profile* and now want to edit the profile on click of button and url become */profile/edit*.

Now I was bit confused between [named views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views) and nested view concept of UI router and tried with both of them but issue remains .

1. using **nested state**

   ```
     .state("profile", {
               url: '/profile',
               controller: 'UserController',
               controllerAs: 'vm',
               templateUrl: 'app/views/user/profile.html',
               data: {
                   requiresAuth: true,
                   pageTitle: 'Profile'
               }
           })
           .state("edit", {
               url: '/edit',
               parent:'profile',
               templateUrl: 'app/views/user/edit_profile.html',
               data: {
                   requiresAuth: true,
                   pageTitle: 'Edit Profile'
               }
           })
   ```

and **profile.html**

```
<div ui-view=""></div>
<button type="button" class="btn fa fa-pencil" ui-sref="edit"></button>
```

in this case my issue is when I click on edit page, it also show the content of parent view too. How to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Child state will be placed at the position of parent's place holder

```
<div ui-view=""></div>
```

That will not hide parent view, just replace that div with child's template

But we really can replace parent view with child's one. The point is to target index.html (root) `ui-view`

```
.state("edit", {
    url: '/edit',
    parent:'profile',
    views: {
        '@': {
            templateUrl: 'app/views/user/edit_profile.html',
         },
    },
    data: {
        requiresAuth: true,
        pageTitle: 'Edit Profile'
    }
})
```

the magical name of the view **`'@'`** says - it is root and unnamed. There are many similar Q & A: [Angular UI Router - Nested States with multiple layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25667660/1679310)